# ReflectPermission("suppressAccessChecks")

Tags: glassfish, securitymanager

I'm having problem with ReflectPermission("suppressAccessChecks"). Whenever I login with authenticated user (user name and password) and try to access a .jsp or any other page in my web application I get

`java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission" "suppressAccessChecks")`.

This happens only when I have  "**Security Manager**" enabled by checking it in GlassFish **Security properties**. When I uncheck this option the web application works.

I would like to know what causes this reason and how to solve it? I think it is not recommended to uncheck **Security Manager** in Security properties.

While I have checked Security Manager in GlassFish Security section, I tried to add following code above my .jsp code

`ReflectPermission refperm = new ReflectPermission("suppressAccessChecks", "");
AccessController.checkPermission(refperm);`

However that didn't helped either.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the glassfish server but, i fixed the same issue in tomcat7 by editing the catalina.policy file and adding the line

permission java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission "suppressAccessChecks";
under grant permissions.