# Giving Different Errors when running Struts2 Application From Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, struts2

I am learning Struts2.By using google i developed a basic application.I developed using eclipse when i was trying to run my application it gives me error 
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
then i exported as war file then i manually copied into tomcat(Apache tomcat 6.0.35) webapps folder then i tried to run now it works fine.So i examine the log files in eclipse

```
Aug 19, 2014 9:19:12 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SpinnerTest' did not find a matching property.
Aug 19, 2014 9:19:12 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:StrutsDemo' did not find a matching property.
Aug 19, 2014 9:19:12 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Aug 19, 2014 9:19:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 625 ms
Aug 19, 2014 9:19:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 19, 2014 9:19:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
Aug 19, 2014 9:19:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.createDispatcher(InitOperations.java:110)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:73)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4072)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4726)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "xwork.loggerFactory" "read")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:366)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:560)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(SecurityManager.java:1302)
at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:706)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.LoggerFactory.getLoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:64)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:45)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.<clinit>(Dispatcher.java:103)
... 21 more

Aug 19, 2014 9:19:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Aug 19, 2014 9:19:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/StrutsDemo] startup failed due to previous errors
```

by following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20331872/struts-gae-java-security-accesscontrolexception-access-denied-of-struts2-core#answer-20483180) i added the below line

```
permission   java.util.PropertyPermission "xwork.loggerFactory", "read";
```

now i am getting the below errors

```
SEVERE: Dispatcher initialization failed
com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.DependencyException: Security manager in use, could not access constructor:        org.apache.struts2.util.fs.JBossFileManager(org.apache.struts2.util.fs.JBossFileManager)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.<init>(ContainerImpl.java:334)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$5.create(ContainerImpl.java:311)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$5.create(ContainerImpl.java:307)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache$CallableCreate.call(ReferenceCache.java:150)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache.internalCreate(ReferenceCache.java:76)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache.get(ReferenceCache.java:116)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getConstructor(ContainerImpl.java:607)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$5.create(ContainerBuilder.java:204)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$3.create(ContainerBuilder.java:93)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$7.call(ContainerBuilder.java:487)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$7.call(ContainerBuilder.java:484)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:584)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder.create(ContainerBuilder.java:484)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.createBootstrapContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:340)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:229)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:489)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4072)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4726)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission" "suppressAccessChecks")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:366)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:560)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.<init>(ContainerImpl.java:330)
... 40 more

Aug 20, 2014 7:50:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
Security manager in use, could not access constructor:     org.apache.struts2.util.fs.JBossFileManager(org.apache.struts2.util.fs.JBossFileManager) -     Class: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector
File: ContainerImpl.java
Method: <init>
Line: 334 - com/opensymphony/xwork2/inject/ContainerImpl.java:334:-1
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:501)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4072)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4726)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.DependencyException: Security manager in use, could not access constructor: org.apache.struts2.util.fs.JBossFileManager(org.apache.struts2.util.fs.JBossFileManager)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.<init>(ContainerImpl.java:334)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$5.create(ContainerImpl.java:311)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$5.create(ContainerImpl.java:307)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache$CallableCreate.call(ReferenceCache.java:150)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache.internalCreate(ReferenceCache.java:76)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache.get(ReferenceCache.java:116)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getConstructor(ContainerImpl.java:607)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$5.create(ContainerBuilder.java:204)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$3.create(ContainerBuilder.java:93)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$7.call(ContainerBuilder.java:487)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$7.call(ContainerBuilder.java:484)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:584)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder.create(ContainerBuilder.java:484)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.createBootstrapContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:340)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:229)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:489)
... 20 more
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission" "suppressAccessChecks")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:366)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:560)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.<init>(ContainerImpl.java:330)
... 40 more

Aug 20, 2014 7:50:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Aug 20, 2014 7:50:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/StrutsDemo] startup failed due to previous errors
```

And Even simple staruts-blank.war is also not working in eclipse which gives the same error,but it is also working fine when manually deploying to tomcat.I am using java7.So can any one please guide me how to solve this?
thanks in advnace

Comment: 99% you have a dependacy management problem, verify if xwork is in the classpath and maven dependacy too

Comment: what is the code of `ContainerImpl.java` file? Are you injecting that class??

Comment: have a look at the latest permission issue..you can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16791237/reflectpermissionsuppressaccesschecks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your tomcat has a SecurityManager activated and struts2 requiere several privileges to work.

Either you can disable that SecurityManager (It is a VM arg) or configure the catalina.policy file to grant permissions to yout WebApp. i.e.

```
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.base}/webapps/<your-webapp>/-" {

    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Comment: if that is the case then how it is successfully running when i deployed and run manually on the same server

Comment: Servers configured in eclipse by default run on a different environment from the installation. The tomcat folders conf, logs, temp, webapps and work are in your workspace metadata. You can check the runtime catalina.base property to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

firstly check web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

check all Jar and mind well not repeat jar in a lib folder.
u get list of all jar file to use run struts project easily.